# When updating a model on a RESTful API, should there be an update endpoint per field? or one endpoint for the model?

Tags: database, api, rest, architecture, backend

For a RESTful API, consider a model schema as follows:

```
MyCoolObject {
  field_a
  field_b
  field_c
}
```

Is it better to **create one** update endpoint to update one or many fields on the model (PUT)? Or **create one endpoint per field** that would only update that one field (PATCH)?

Answer (score 0):

Heuristic: how do you GET the information from your API?

Typically if you get the information a single resource with all of the information included in its representation...

```
GET /my-cool-object
```

Then you should also edit that information using the same resource

```
PUT /my-cool-object
PATCH /my-cool-object
POST /my-cool-object
```

---

In cases where you get the information from multiple resources (presumably via links)

```
GET /my-cool-object
GET /my-cool-object/a
GET /my-cool-object/b
GET /my-cool-object/c
```

Then you would normally edit the information in its own resource

```
PUT /my-cool-object/a
PATCH /my-cool-object/a
POST /my-cool-object/a
```